# Two layouts for a single activity

Tags: android

Can i give two layouts for a single activity?? If yes, then how can i join them?? First layout should contain heading and the other one will be used in list adapter and repeated for every item in the list..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is to have an activity layout containing the header and the list view. And on the other side, a row layout that will be used by a custom adapter for your list view.

Here is a short tutorial covering what you want to acheive: [custom-listview-items-and-adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

Answer (score 1):

You can have one layout for your `Activity` and use the following command to include a sub-layout :

`<include android:layout="@layout/layout_name" />`